# Добавление в Memo-поле строк из Edit

Tags: delphi

Нужно ввести данные в Edit'ы а потом их вывести в Memo, если нажат тот или иной RadioButton.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fio,date,com:string;
  mark,num:integer;
begin
  Edit1.Text:=fio;
  Edit2.Text:=date;
  mark:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text);
  num:=StrToInt(Edit4.Text);
  Edit5.Text:=com;

  if RadioButton1.Checked then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(fio + date + IntToStr(mark))
  else
    if RadioButton2.Checked then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(fio + IntToStr(num) + date)
    else
      if RadioButton3.Checked then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(fio + date + com);
end;
```

Что не так в коде и как это поправить?

Comment: А в чём проблема?
Ошибки не вижу! Вот только смысла в переводе стринг-интегер-стринг не вижу (это mark и num)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Переводить данные из string в integer в данном случае бессмысленно. убирайте это.
там, где задаете содержимое для Edit-ов, его возьмите в кавычки, например:
Edit1.Text := 'fio';
Если конечно, fio и прочее вы действительно не используете как переменные. Вот только какой в них смысл, если вы будете менять данные в Edit-ах.
Забирайте по клику данные напрямую, не создавая лишних переменных. А начальные надписи в Edit-ах задайте на FormCreate, или в Design Time-е.
Вместо нескольких RadioButton удобнее использовать RadioGroup.
Также, при добавлении строк в Memo, между добавляемыми значениями переменных, вставье пробел, т.е. к примеру:
Memo1.Lines.Add(fio + ' ' + date + ' ' + IntToStr(mark))

Это для начала.

Кстати, данные в Edit-ы Вы вводите руками, когда программа запущена, или задаете изначально, и Вам требуется просто отобразить их в Edit?

Вот код:

```
type
  TF_Main = class(TForm)
    Memo: TMemo;      // Ваше Memo
    eFIO: TEdit;      // Edit для ввода фамилии, имени и отчества
    eBDate: TEdit;    // Edit для ввода даты рождения
    rbBDFIO: TRadioButton;   // RadioButton, если выбран он, то выводится Др + ФИО
    rbFIOBD: TRadioButton;   // RadioButton, если выбран он, то выводится ФИО + Др
    btnStart: TButton;       // кнопка, по клику на которой из полей Edit, данные заносятся в Memo
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  F_Main: TF_Main;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TF_Main.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if rbBDFIO.Checked=True then
    Memo.Lines.Add(eBDate.Text + ', ' + eFIO.Text)
    else
      Memo.Lines.Add(eFIO.Text + ', ' + eBDate.Text);
end;

procedure TF_Main.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // при создании формы задаем текст в Edit-ах
  eFIO.Text   := 'Ф.И.О.';        // поле, где будут введены ФИО
  eBDate.Text := 'Дата рождения'; // поле для даты рождения
end;

end.
```

Вместо того, чтобы задавать начальный текст в поле Edit-ов, я советовал бы около каждого Edit, разместить Label :) Смотрелось бы лучше, да и не было бы мороки с выделением текста в эдитах, к тому же, событие FormCreate можно было бы не использовать. Осталось бы только в дизайн-тайме задать caption для каждого из лэйблов и все.

Comment: нужно вводить данные руками

проблема в том, что когда нажимаю кнопку Button, у меня все данные исчезают, и не добавляются в memo

RadioGroup использовать по заданию не нужно к сожалению..

Comment: Ну, раз RadioButton, то пусть будут они) Если данные вводятся руками, тогда Вы можете избавиться от всех переменных. Вам нужно просто забирать данные из полей Edit-ов и нужным образом их группируя, выводить в Memo. Правильно я понял?

Comment: я приведу Вам код, для случая, когда нужно в Эдиты ввести дату рождения и ФИО человека, а потом их вывести в Мемо по нажатию кнопки, каким-либо образом в зависимости от выбранного RadioButton. А Вы по аналогии с этим кодом уже сможете спокойно поменять свой.)

Comment: да, все верно поняли. Бедный студент будет признателен вам за помощь)

Comment: :) Код выше, в ответе)

Comment: вот спасибо так спасибо!!!

Comment: нет проблем) рад был помочь)

Answer (score -1):

вместо

```
Edit1.Text:=fio;
Edit2.Text:=date;
...
Edit5.Text:=com;
```

напишите

```
fio:=Edit1.Text;
date:=Edit2.Text;
...
com:=Edit5.Text;
```

Comment: на кой, извините, там вообще нужны переменные? это лишнее.

Comment: Пусть учатся отделять интерфейсную часть от алгоритмической

Comment: Это да, но если человек возьмет за правило на каждый элемент интерфейса заводить переменную, получится тот же говнокод. Особенно, если элементов на форме будет куча и все они с именами вроде Edit1, Edit2,...,Edit(n).

Comment: Не согласен? но переубеждать не буду.

Comment: Аналогично.
Все приходит с опытом. (с)